# gnome: on-screen keyboard not showing up, scrolling in firefox not working

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, touch, gnome, touchscreen

I have a setup with a touch screen attached via USB to a linux machine running Gnome 42/Ubuntu 22.04. Unfortunately the on-screen keyboard doesn't show up in Firefox and also swiping across the page to scroll results in the text being selected.

I believe there is a bug with Gnome/Mutter not being in touch mode. Running the snippet

```
gdbus call --session \
--dest org.gnome.Shell \
--object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
--method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
'imports.gi.Clutter.get_default_backend().get_default_seat().touch_mode'
```

Results in `(false, '')`. Is there a way to force touch mode? Is this the real problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the keyboard not showing up.  But the scroll thing is fixed by changing two settings in firefox.

1. Open `about:config`
2. Find `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled` set it to 1
3. Open `pam_env.conf` found in `/etc/security/`
4. On a new line, append `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2 DEFAULT=1`
5. Reboot

Your Firefox install will now start as if the device is a tablet, rather than a desktop.  Meaning you can pinch/zoom etc. with the touch screen.